# Is k^3 O(n^2) for some constant k > 1?

Tags: asymptotics

On the one hand a constant should be upper bounded by a variable which increases. But I'm not really sure if this is the case, as $k^3$ is a higher power than $n^2$. I'm don't know how to approach this problem as I don't really know take the limit of the two functions and that's normally what I would do.

How would one approach this problem?

Comment: You seem to be implying that $k^3$ is a constant and hence $k^3=O(1)=O(n^2)$

Comment: If $k$ is a constant, then $k^3$ is a constant as well, so by definition it is $O(1)$

Comment: Do you want $k^3=O(n^2)$ ($n\to +\infty$). In this case yes, because $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{k^3}{n^2}=0$, so $(k^3/n^2)$ is bounded. If $k$ is big, you must consider $n$ very large.